# Android app starts automatically when parse.com is integrated

Tags: android, parse-platform

Since i integrated the push api of parse.com, my app starts automatically in the background when the device is started. You can see it in the list of running apps.

I am using parse 1.3.5
I don't want the app to run in the background.

Any ideas how to get around this?

Manifest:

```
  <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

  <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
```

Comment: Did you implemented any `Broad Cast Receiver`? post it....

Comment: No I didn't. Used the standard parse receiver (see my edit)